# Response to prompt dialog not moving to the next waterfall step

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

When I run the application for the first time, I am doing some initialization steps like asking for name and the communication mode(chat or speak), I used BeginDialogAsync to start the respective prompt dialog. But after responding to the prompt, it goes back to the MainDialog.cs I created, to check user input with LUIS, instead of going to the next waterfall step.

CODE

OptionsDialog.cs

```
    private void InitializeWaterfallDialog()
    {
        var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            InitialStepAsync,
            FinalStepAsync
        };

        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog($"{nameof(OptionsDialog)}.mainFlow", waterfallSteps));
        AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt($"{nameof(OptionsDialog)}.communicationMode"));

        InitialDialogId = $"{nameof(OptionsDialog)}.mainFlow";
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InitialStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync($"{nameof(OptionsDialog)}.communicationMode",
            new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please select how you want to continue interacting with me."),
                Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(new List<string> { "Chat", "Speak" }),
            }, cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> FinalStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        var reply = MessageFactory.Attachment(attachments);
        switch (((FoundChoice)stepContext.Result).Value)
        {
            case "Chat":
                reply.Text = "Type something to start";
                break;
            case "Speak":
                reply.Text = "This option is yet to be configured. Continuing with chat option. Type something to start";
                break;
        }
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
        return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

MainDialog.cs

```
    private void InitializeWaterfallDialog()
    {
        var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            InitialStepAsync,
            FinalStepAsync
        };

        AddDialog(new OptionsDialog($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.options", _botStateService));
        AddDialog(new GreetingDialog($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.greeting", _botStateService));
        AddDialog(new RevenueDialog($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.revenue", _botStateService, _botServices, _financialServices, _currencyService));
        AddDialog(new QuarterlyRevenueDialog($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.quarterlyRevenue", _botStateService, _botServices, _financialServices, _currencyService));
        AddDialog(new ProfitDialog($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.profit", _botStateService, _botServices, _financialServices, _currencyService));
        AddDialog(new QuarterlyProfitDialog($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.quarterlyProfit", _botStateService, _botServices, _financialServices, _currencyService));
        AddDialog(new StockPriceDialog($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.stockPrice", _botStateService, _botServices, _financialServices, _currencyService));
        AddDialog(new PersonNameDialog($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.personName", _botStateService, _botServices));
        AddDialog(new FarewellDialog($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.farewell", _botStateService, _botServices));
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.mainFlow", waterfallSteps));

        InitialDialogId = $"{nameof(MainDialog)}.mainFlow";
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InitialStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            UserProfile userProfile = await _botStateService.UserProfileAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context, () => new UserProfile());
            var recognizerResult = await _botServices.Dispatch.RecognizeAsync(stepContext.Context, cancellationToken);
            // Top intent tell us which cognitive service to use.
            var topIntent = recognizerResult?.GetTopScoringIntent();
            if(userProfile.HasRestartedConversation)
            {
                userProfile.HasRestartedConversation = false;
                return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.options", null, cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                switch (topIntent?.intent)
                {
                    case "GreetingIntent":
                        return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.greeting", null, cancellationToken);
                    case "FindRevenueIntent":
                        return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.revenue", null, cancellationToken);
                    case "FindQuarterlyRevenueIntent":
                        return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.quarterlyRevenue", null, cancellationToken);
                    case "FindProfitIntent":
                        return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.profit", null, cancellationToken);
                    case "FindQuarterlyProfitIntent":
                        return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.quarterlyProfit", null, cancellationToken);
                    case "FindStockPriceIntent":
                        return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.stockPrice", null, cancellationToken);
                    case "FindPersonNameIntent":
                        return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.personName", null, cancellationToken);
                    case "FarewellIntent":
                        return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.farewell", null, cancellationToken);
                    case "CommunicationSelectIntent":
                        return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.options", null, cancellationToken);
                    case null:
                        break;
                    default:
                        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Sorry, I don’t have an answer for that. " +
                            $"(Please try something like 'What is revenue of google?')"), cancellationToken);
                        break;
                }
            }
            await _botStateService.UserProfileAccessor.SetAsync(stepContext.Context, userProfile);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Sorry, there was an error sending your message. Please try again."), cancellationToken);
        }
        return await stepContext.NextAsync(null, cancellationToken);
    }
```

After giving a response to the prompt in InitialStepAsync in OptionsDialog, it should go the next waterfall step, FinalStepAsync but it is going to the MainDialog and checking the response with LUIS.

The activity trigger code in the main bot program, DialogBot.cs:

```
    public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

        // Save any state changes that might have occured during the turn.
        await _botStateService.UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
        await _botStateService.ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Running dialog with Message Activity.");

        // Run the Dialog with the new message Activity.
        await _dialog.Run(turnContext, _botStateService.DialogStateAccessor, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Run method:

```
    public static async Task Run(this Dialog dialog, ITurnContext turnContext, IStatePropertyAccessor<DialogState> accessor, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var dialogSet = new DialogSet(accessor);
        dialogSet.Add(dialog);

        var dialogContext = await dialogSet.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
        var results = await dialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);
        if (results.Status == DialogTurnStatus.Empty)
        {
            await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(dialog.Id, null, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

The issue here is that after responding to the prompt, it is going to BeginDialogAsync instead of ContinueDialogAsync which is only happening the first time I run the bot. If I trigger the OptionsDialog any time later, the waterfall steps are being run properly.

Comment: Because of your use of `InitialDialogId`, I am going to assume both `MainDialog` and `OptionsDialog` are component dialogs. Your code seems similar to the [CoreBot sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot). There's nothing obviously wrong with it. You say you're doing initialization steps when you run the application for the first time, though I presume you mean when you start a conversation with a user. Why does it look like you're starting `OptionsDialog` in response to a LUIS intent and not when the conversation starts?

Comment: Since I'm starting all the dialogs in the MainDialog.cs, I figured that's where I can start a dialog as an initialization step. Where else can I start a dialog?

Comment: You misunderstand me. Your question starts with "When I run the application for the first time, I am doing some initialization steps like asking for name and the communication mode(chat or speak)." This implies that both MainDialog.greeting and MainDialog.options are meant to run at the start of a conversation, and yet in your code the only dialog you're starting automatically is MainDialog.greeting. How is MainDialog.options started without hitting the LUIS intent? Is it called from within MainDialog.greeting?

Comment: Forgive me. My mistake. I forgot to edit my code to have MainDialog.options. "yet in your code the only dialog you're starting automatically is MainDialog.greeting" Yes. It was MainDialog.options before I replaced it with MainDialog.greeting to check if there was an issue only with options dialog. There wasn't. The only problem here is that when I begin a prompt dialog in if(userProfile.HasRestartedConversation), the response to it is not going to the next waterfall step in the respective dialog. The response is coming to MainDialog and checking against LUIS to see which Intent it belongs to.

Comment: Would you go ahead and create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and either post it here or email it to me?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am going through the bot framework documentation to understand more about it. Will figure it out.